# How to fire this function for my component (React Native)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this piece of code of a component that

```
   class List extends Component {       
   ...

   render() {
    ...
    return
     <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this.props.clearFilter()}>
     </TouchableHighlight>
    ...
    }
   ...
   }
```

The parent:

```
    class Nav extends Component {
     ...
     // render implements renderscene for navigator

     renderScene(route, navigator){
     ...
     return (
     <List 
       navigator={navigator}
       clearFilter={this.props.clearFilter}
       ref={component => this._list = component}/>
     );
     }
```

and:

```
export default class App extends Component {

applyfilter(){
//...
}

  constructor(props){
      ...
      this.applyfilter = this.applyfilter.bind(this);
  }
  clearFilter(){
    this.setState(
      {
        _filter:null,
        _filterValue:"",
      }, ()=>{this.applyFilter();}
    );

  _renderScene = ({ route }) => {
      return <Nav ref={component => this._nav = component} clearFilter={this.clearFilter.bind(this)}/>;
...

}
```

So I am passing the `clearFilter()` function along from App to Nav, and Nav passes it on to List. When List's button is pressed, I want the clearFilter() of App to fire, but for it does not compute as a function for some reason.

I am getting `undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this3.applyFilter()')` every time the button is pressed.

How to fire clearFilter for App from the button of List?

Comment: It seems `clearFilter` gets called and it is `applyFilter` in the setState callback that is undefined. Have you remembered to bind it?

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention:     this.applyfilter = this.applyfilter.bind(this); is defined in the constructor of App, editing

Comment: applyFilter seems to be not defined...

Comment: @Ted, can you add the whole code? I'd like to copy and paste it, I cant help you right now because I cant identify if there is a tipping problem or a logic problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a typo mistake: You're creating the function as `applyfilter`but you're invoking it as `applyFilter` inside your `clearFilter` function. That's why it's throwing an error that it's `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you aren't missing some code here, `this.applyfilter` seems to be not defined anywhere.

Comment: Can you update the code so? If `applyFilter` is defined aouside of App's scope you must remove `this`.

Comment: Did you bind `_renderScene` ?

Comment: in Nav, it is bound, yes

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not clearly formatted. looks like you have declared applyFilter outside the class. define it after constructor inside the class.

Personally I prefer using `clearFilter={()=> {this.clearFilter()}}` instead of `clearFilter={this.clearFilter.bind(this)}`

Same for `applyFilter`.

```js
class Button extends Components {
  render(){
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={()=>{ this.props.clearFilter() }}
      >
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

class List extends Components {
  render(){
    return(
      <Button
        clearFilter={()=>{ this.props.clearFilter() }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default class Mainapp extends Components {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  clearFilter(){
    //// do something
    this.applyFilter();
  }

  applyFilter(){
    //// do something
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <List
          clearFilter={()=>{ this.clearFilter() }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```